# Use raw data instead of json in highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have been using this example

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/

Data example:

```
[Date.UTC(1971, 2, 11), 1.18],
[Date.UTC(1971, 3, 11), 1.19],
[Date.UTC(1971, 4, 1), 1.85],
```

to act as a template for the charts I have been creating, however I need to create a synchronised chart, the only example I can find for this is

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/synchronized-charts/

Uses, to acquire the data:

```
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=activity.json&callback=?', function (activity)
```

Though this uses json to acquire the data which I am not familiar with, I need to be able to input data using the direct method in the first example. I am creating dynamic graphs on demand, so I need to use the first method so I can use php to input data. How can I change the second example to accept such data input?

Comment: Take the data in JSON format and then process it into whatever format you want it in. A JSON data structure is designed to be easily used by javascript as either an array or an object

Comment: I'm not looking to take data, I am supplying the data, I want to find out how to supply it in the format above,

Comment: Have a look at `json_encode()` all you need to do is create the array and fill it with the objects as required.

Comment: I'll take a look at it, will that method work seamlessly with the second example? Would I just have to replace the url with the json string?

Comment: No you won't have to replace the URL there, the jsonp.php file should just use json_encode() a PHP array that contains the data you want to send.

Comment: @AchrafAlmouloudi So I just replace 'getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=activity.json&callback=?'' with json_encode(data...) ? If not can you give me an example?

Comment: No, the json_encode() function is a PHP one. If you're creating a PHP page that'll be the URL then you'll have to fill a PHP array with the data and output (echo) it as such "echo json_encore($array);" then in JavaScript, to get the values from getJSON() output, go to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ have a look at the last 2 examples that shows how to parse the JSON values.